# how to cache the streaming video using Avplayer for the server

Tags: ipad, video-streaming, audio-streaming, avplayer

I need a mechanism to progressively stream video content stored in my local cache using AVPlayer.

how can i stored or used the video\audio file from cache while it streaming for the server using AVplayer.

please give me central idea related to this to solve my problem..

while i play first time video something is stored in application folder like tmp\mediacache\diskcacherepository.plist.
what was that? or should i used that key path..

please ans me n solve my problem.